# Are React Functional Components better than regular functions?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization

Today I face an interesting case and pop out a question
Eg: You have to create columns for the table, is creating a Columns component or creating a utility function named generateColumns is better? As I know, React Component is also a normal function but which solution is better?

```js
// generateColumns.ts
export const generateColumns(columns: Array<string>){
  return columns &&
         columns.length > 0 &&
         columns.map((col, index) => <th>{col}</th>)}
}

// Using in component
<Table>
  {generateColumns(columns)}
</Table>
```

```js
// Columns.tsx
type ColumnsProps = {
  columns: Array<string>;
};

const Columns: React.VFC<ColumnsProps> = ({ columns }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {columns &&
        columns.length > 0 &&
        columns.map((col, index) => <th key={index}>{col}</th>)}
    </tr>
  );
};

export default Columns;

// Using in component
<Table>
  <Columns columns={columns} />
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "React Component is also a normal function."

This statement is wrong in context of rendering.

---

React component is a function which you **MOUNT** by using React API.
Statements using JSX syntax are [synthetic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) for `React.createElement` calls.

```
// MOUNTS the component
<Columns columns={columns} />
```

While "normal function" call is [simply whats defined by JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

**Therefore,** there is a **MAJOR different** between the two calls, when you MOUNT a component you receive all properties of a component such as lifecycles and skipping renders - components trigger [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) process.

A call of "normal function" doesn't have any of those, and will be **called on every render** (log inside your "normal function" to test it).

> Questions of "whats better" are opinionated based so I didnt include it in my answer, it always depends on the context, sometimes function calls returning JSX are appropriative if there are extensive mounts. Decide yourself by reviewing the preferences.